# global variable with different values

Tags: objective-c, hyperlink, global

I have question about global variable in Objective-C.

I have two .m files : file1.m and file2.m, and one .h file : file.h

I want to declare a global variable in .h and this variable has two different values defined by .m files.

I do this :

In .h file :

```
extern NSString * const myVar;
```

In file1.m :

```
NSString * const myVar = @"value 1";
```

In file2.m :

```
NSString * const myVar = @"value 2";
```

But it doesn't link, I have error "duplicate symbols".

I understand this error, but I can't solve it to do what I want.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not declare it in the .h file, but declare it in each .m file where you use it (like now) and put "static" in front of the declaration

```
static NSString * const myVar = @"value 2";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a global variable it is global .. so it is the same everywhere. a variable can't hold two different values.

if you want different values in different files, then don't make them global.

Comment: In file1.m, I use it as global because it is called in multiple functions, so it must be global. And the same in file2.m.

Comment: @TheFrancisOne Just the opposite as Bastian said.

Comment: well.. then you need just a static variable ... it won't need to be project global... so two as joris mans said.. don't include it in the header and make it static

Answer (score 0):

Put

`NSString * const myVar = @"value 2";`

only in one .m.

Comment: I can't, it will define one value for my global, and I want it have a different value in each .m file.

Comment: If you want it to have different values, then you need two variables, not a global one. A global one has, by definition, the same value everywhere, since it's the same variable.